# Reduce service time for consecutive pickups / deliveries on same locations

Tags: java, algorithm, vehicle-routing, jsprit

Is it possible to reduce service time for consecutive shipment pickups/deliveries on same coordinates during solution search?

For example:
There are four shipments = 4 pickups & 4 deliveries. All shipments picked from same locations, and delivered from to same locations.

Default pickup / delivery service time = 60 seconds.

Default result:

```
P1 (60s), P2 (60s), P3 (60s), P4 (60s), D1 (60s), D2 (60s), D3 (60s), D4 (60s)
Total service time = 480 seconds.
```

Result with service time reduction for consecutive activities:

```
P1 (60s), P2 (0s), P3 (0s), P4 (0s), D1 (60s), D2 (0s), D3 (0s), D4 (0s)
Total service time = 120 seconds.
```

How to produce solution that would have service times from result above? Maybe there is a way to influence algorithm in a way that would truncate service times?